# ng-maxlength preventing a valid value from being databound to input field

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have the following field in a form:

```
<input type="text" name="dedicatedstaff" ng-model="staffingRecord.dedicatedStaff"
      tabindex="9" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,4}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" ng-maxlength="7" />
```

The form is to edit an existing record.  No matter what value is in the existing record, the field fails validation and the databind becomes undefined.  Some example values that exist on the records are 1, 2.5, 12.5, 99.25, 4.0.  I believe every one of these should pass both the pattern and maxlength validations, but it isn't working.  I've checked the model and the values are present when loading the form.

When I remove the ng-maxlength directive and just have the ng-pattern, it works fine and those values pass validation.  If I remove ng-pattern and just have max-length, it fails.  It also doesn't matter if the INPUT is of type text or number.  If ng-maxlength is present, it fails.  Browser also does not make a difference (tested Chrome, IE & Firefox).  I have also verified that it is the maxlength error in the error list.

I am also using ng-maxlength with almost every other field on this particular form, and they also work just fine.  And if I type the exact values listed above after form load when ng-maxlength is present validates fine at that point.  But that's not a reasonable workflow to make the client type the values over again every time they load the form.

I don't understand it as I use this same pattern in other forms within the app and they work fine.  I can get by with just ng-pattern on this particular field, but I would much rather figure out why, in this one case, it won't validate properly on load.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.14, with JQuery 1.9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was actually the INPUT type after all.  After further testing, I realized my initial test of that variation was incorrect.  Changing the INPUT type to NUMBER fixed the validation issues.

```
<input type="number" name="dedicatedstaff" ng-model="staffingRecord.dedicatedStaff"
      tabindex="9" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{0,4}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" ng-maxlength="7" />
```